# Change the value of array in native method

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I want to change every value of 2 dementional array in native method (`jobjectArray`). When I'm debugging through the code, debuger displays that the `*body` value of this pointer is being changed. However after returning to the java files, arrays is untouched. What am I doing wrong?

C++ class:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_model_CppDllLibrary_convertToNegative
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray image, jint width, jint height) {
printf("Java_model_CppDllLibrary_convertToNegative");

for (int i = 0; i<height; i++) {
    jintArray oneDim = (jintArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(image,i);
    for (int j = 0; j<width; j++) {
        jint *body = env->GetIntArrayElements(oneDim, false);
        int p = body[j];
        int a = (p >> 24) & 0xff;
        int r = (p >> 16) & 0xff;
        int g = (p >> 8) & 0xff;
        int b = p & 0xff;
        r = 255 - r;
        g = 255 - g;
        b = 255 - b;
        p = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        *body = p;
        //env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(oneDim, body, 0);
    }
}
}
```

Java class:

```
int pixels[][] = ImageConverter.converToArrayOfPixels(bufferedImage);
    CppDllLibrary tst = new CppDllLibrary();
    tst.convertToNegative(pixels,pixels[0].length,pixels.length);
```

Comment: Why did you remove the call to `ReleaseIntArrayElements`? You should always release the elements when you're done with them. Plus, `ReleaseIntArrayElements` is where the copy-back to the Java array will take place in case `GetIntArrayElements` returned a copy of the data (hint: passing `false` to `GetIntArrayElements` does not mean that you won't be getting a copy).

Comment: Uncommenting this line didn't solve my problem. The .dll still don't return proper values @Michael.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe. For me, modifying an array in native code works fine. Of course, your `Get/ReleaseIntArrayElements` calls should be _outside_ the inner loop, not inside them. And the inner loop should be writing the result to `body[j]`, not to `*body`.